# How to check if three numbers are different in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, integer, logic

I am doing an activity to learn Kotlin that I can't figure out. I am new to coding and Kotlin so excuse me for my mistakes and lack of knowledge.

This is the description of the activity:

*Write a program that reads three numbers and checks if they all are different (i.e. no number equals to any other).
The program is to output true or false.*

*Sample Input 1:*

```
5
5
9
```

*Sample Output 1:*

```
false
```

*Sample Input 2:*

```
1
2
3
```

*Sample Output 2:*

```
true
```

I have tried different approaches but I none of them has worked, so if anyone could help me with this, I would really appreciate it.

```
fun main() {
    val num = readLine()!!.toInt()
    val num1 = readLine()!!.toInt()
    val num2 = readLine()!!.toInt()
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Getting some clarification on the exercise would be of use to those trying to help. Namely: how will the numbers be supplied to the program? Through the standard input? Will a function be called with an array of the numbers? Etc.

Comment: Also, I see you've stated that you have nothing to show, but _literally anything_ is better than nothing. Any wrong approaches you've taken would be very informative in how best to instruct you. Just getting a solution will allow you to proceed, but it won't be very elucidating for you

Comment: As @jonny said, we need to see some effort. This isn't a free code writing service or even a tutorial service. We're here to help you with your work. Maybe do some research on how to compare numbers first, then see if that can get you anywhere.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to imply that I want someone to do it for me. I didn't show the code because I felt like it wouldn't help, I see now that I was wrong. I have edited it with the code I wrote. This activity is from Jetbrains Academy and the numbers are provided by it when you run the code, that's why I used a readLIne(). Hope this helps and again, sorry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a list and from the list a set. A set cannot contain duplicate entries. And now compare the number of elements between list and set.

```
  val xs = listOf(num,num1,num2)
  val result = xs.size == xs.toSet().size   // true or false
```

If it's always three numbers you can write it like that:

```
  val result = setOf(num, num1, num2).size == 3
```

Comment: This seems quite unnecessary for a simple three number comparison?

Comment: @HenryTwist It also works for four numbers and even for five numbers. It scales very well.

Comment: Yes of course, I just presume the OP is learning coding for the first time, so this doesn't really teach what the activity was probably trying to.

Comment: Just realised I mis-read the question as checking whether the numbers were all equal. So this is the most concise solution as it avoids having to check each pair.

Answer (score 2):

Here you simply have to check that each pair is different. So you want something like this:

```
fun areAllDifferent(n1: Int, n2: Int, n3: Int) = /* n1 != n2 and n2 != n3 and n1 != n3 */
```

This can then be extended to compare n numbers using the same logic by looping through each pair and checking for equality:

```
fun areAllDifferent(vararg numbers: Int) {

   for (i in numbers.indices) {

        for (j in numbers.indices) {

            if (/* the ith and jth numbers are equal and i != j */) return false
    }

    return true
}
```

---

For a more concise solution however, I would take a look at the answer from @Twistleton. It also has a lower time complexity (`O(n)` compared to `O(n2)` here) however note that it introduces additional space complexity (`O(n)`) if `n` is large.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I thought I understood it now after reading your reply but it keeps telling me that it's wrong. I leave here the code that I made. (I put a string in the println as it specifies that the output has to be a string). 

fun main() {
    val num1 = readLine()!!.toInt()
    val num2 = readLine()!!.toInt()
    val num3 = readLine()!!.toInt()
    if ((num1 == num2) && (num2 == num3)) {
        println("true")
    } else {
        println("false")
    }
    
}

Comment: Assuming that the code isn't all on the same line (that's how the comment formatted it), this runs fine? It prints `true` if the inputs are all equal and `false` otherwise! So I am not sure what the issue is. Are you sure you have read the task correctly? Maybe put a link to it if you can or copy the important parts.

Comment: Yeah it's not all on one line, I wasn't sure how to format it on the comment. I posted on imgur two images, one with the description of the task and another one with the code I wrote plus the error message. Hope it helps. imgur.com/a/4lLUSbL

Comment: Oh sorry I read the question wrong, my solution is for when they're equal, not different. I would actually recommend the other answer then in this case!

Comment: I've edited mine to fit the problem. I think it's more useful to understand the concept, but the other answer is more concise.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to edit it and solving my questions! My only problem now is that I don't understand what setOf(num, num1, num2).size == 3 exactly does. Could you give me a short explanation about what this does maybe? Don't want to bother too much though!

Comment: @Pauliecode A set removes duplicate entries. Duplicate numbers are therefore removed. If subsequently the size of the set is three, each number was unique.

Comment: @Pauliecode Try:  setOf(2,2,2).size    the result is 1 - all duplicate numbers are removed.

Comment: Sets are collections of distinct numbers, you can't add duplicates. So if a set of all your numbers is the same size as the original list of numbers, they must all be different.

Comment: setOf(1,2,3).size will return 3 for three different numbers.

Comment: Ohhh okay!! I understand it now, I have been testing on the IDE as well to see it practically and it helped a lot. Thank you guys for the replies ^^